# getting the lemma of a word using wordnet

Tags: php, nlp, wordnet, lemmatization, morphological-analysis

How can I get the lemma for a given word using Wordnet. I couldn't seem to find in the wordnet documentation what i want.  http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wn.1WN.html

For example for the word "books" i want to get "book" , ashes => ash , booking => book, apples => apple .... etc.

i want to achieve this using wordnet in command line and I cant find exact options to retrieve such case.

A php solution would also be of great help because I originally intend to use the wordnet php API but it seems the current one in their website isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Morphy is a morphological processor native to WordNet. The WordNet interfaces invoke Morphy to lemmatize a word as part of the lookup process (e.g. you query "enlightened", it returns the results for both "enlightened" and, via Morphy, "enlighten").

The interfaces don't include a feature that allows a user to directly access Morphy, so using it in command line is only possible if you write your own program using one of the WordNet APIs. You can find [documentation](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/morph.3WN.html) for Morphy at the WordNet site.

As near as I can tell, the [PHP interface](http://www.foxsurfer.com/wordnet/) is still available, although you may need to use WordNet 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use another tool try [TreeTagger](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TreeTagger/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that WordNet implements it natively. NLTK has Morphy, which precisely does what you want, but it is implemented in Python though. You can write a small Python program to take input from the command line and return the lemma.

Search for 'Morphy' in the following link:
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetCorpusReader-class.html

nltk.WordNetLemmatizer() also does the job. Search for 'Lemmatization' in the following link:
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch03.html

NLTK website : http://www.nltk.org/

Answer (score 1):

The WordNetLemmatizer in the nltk library will do what you need. here is python3 code:

```
#!Python3 -- this is lemmatize_s.py
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
print ("This program will lemmatize your input until you ask for it to 'end'.")
while True:
    sentence = input("Type one or more words (or 'end') and press enter:")
    if (sentence == "end"):
        break
    tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    Output=[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens]
    print (Output);
```

Running this from the command line:

```
eyeMac2016:james$ python3 lemmatize_s.py
This program will lemmatize your input until you ask for it to 'end'.
Type one or more words  (or 'end') and press enter:books ashes
['book', 'ash']
Type one or more words  (or 'end') and press enter:end
eyeMac2016:james$
```